# Laravel 8 route() does not localize strings

Tags: laravel, localization, translation, laravel-routing, laravel-8

**EDIT: found the answer to all my questions: https://github.com/codezero-be/laravel-localized-routes (and, of course, 42).**

I'm working on a multi-language website where the URL's contain localized strings. For instance:

https://site/en/*members*/john-doe
https://site/nl/*leden*/john-doe
(and so for every language)

In web.php, I prefixed my routes. Via middleware, I set the current language (retrieved from the first URL-segment). This works fine for everything (both in controllers and in blade)... except for the URLs generated by **route()**. They are always in the default language. Even though everything else is correctly localized. If I dump app()->getLocale() in a controller of blade it shows the correct language. Only the URLs generated by the route()-function are always in the default fallback language.

I've tried moving my middleware-class higher up in the middleware-groups list. That didn't make a difference.

**web.php**

```
Route::prefix('{lang}')->group(function() {
        Route::get(trans('routes.members') . '/{username}/', 'MembersController@profile')
            ->name('members.show');
}
```

**SetLanguage middleware**

```
... 
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)  
{  
        $lang = $request->segment(1) ?? app()->getLocale(); 

        //set app language  
        app()->setLocale($lang);  
        //set default url parameter  
        URL::defaults(['lang' => $lang]);  
        return $next($request);  
    }  
...
```

**App\Http\Kernel.php**

```
...
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\SetLanguage::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\UserLastSeenAt::class,
        ],
        ...
```

Comment: I found this as a possible solution, but it seems a bit ... overkill. If the route()-function uses the language I set before calling it I'm good :) 

https://mydnic.be/post/how-to-build-an-efficient-and-seo-friendly-multilingual-architecture-in-laravel-v2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it (with a little help from a friend)

In the AppServiceProvider's boot function I've added

```
 public function boot(Request $request)
 {
        //set app language
        app()->setLocale($request->segment(1) ?? app()->getLocale());
  }
```

& the SetLanguage-middleware now only contains

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    //set default url parameter
    URL::defaults(['lang' => app()->getLocale()]);
     return $next($request);
 }
```

That did the trick!

Comment: Something else I discovered: trans('file.key', [], 'fr') fetches the french-value of key. Regardles of the current app-locale.